# Geometry simplification for large scale aggregations in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, simplify, aggregation

When aggregating on a large scale in GEE, does geometry simplification matter?

For example, when aggregating climate data on 30 km/pixel (e.g. [NEX-GDDP](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_NEX-GDDP)), does it make computational sense to change between the [simplified](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDOS_LSIB_SIMPLE_2017) and [detailed](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDOS_LSIB_2017) version of LSIB dataset (not to take into account that simplified version has some islands excluded).